# Does the series corresponding to a Cauchy sequence **always** converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, absolute-convergence

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and consider a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$.

Is it true that the corresponding series of our Cauchy sequence, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$, **always** converges absolutely? (that is to say $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \|x_i\|_X$ converges)

If not, what are some counter examples to elucidate the point?

Comment: $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = 13$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, but $\sum x_n$ does not converge at all.

Comment: additionally to Martin R's comment, maybe to do anything with cauchyness and convergence, you maybe want to assume that your space in complete

Comment: I understand that in a complete NVS every Cauchy sequence must converge (by definition). I was wondering whether in a purely NVS the series corresponding to a Cauchy sequence was guaranteed to converge absolutely.

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames: It seems that you are mixing up the *sequence* and the *series.* A convergent sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, but that does not imply the convergence of of the series $\sum x_n$ at all, neither absolutely nor conditionally.

Comment: This relates to another question - which I will now ask and then link to this one - @MartinR, if you post your counter example as an answer I will happily accept.

Comment: Is the above not in contradiction to this idea here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513073/is-this-valid-every-cauchy-sequence-in-a-normed-space-is-absolutely-convergent?rq=1

Comment: Also, suppose $(x_{n})$ converges to 0, then still if $\|x_{n}\|=\frac{1}{n}\|$ the series will not converge absolutely.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a *sequence* $(x_n)$ we have the following implications:
$$
\begin{matrix}
 (x_n)_n \text{ convergent} & \implies & (x_n)_n \text{ Cauchy} \\
 \Downarrow & & \Downarrow \\
 (\Vert x_n \Vert )_n \text{ convergent} & \implies & (\Vert x_n \Vert )_n \text{ Cauchy} \\
\end{matrix}
$$
(and the “horizontal” implications are equivalences if $X$ is complete).

But none of this implies that the corresponding *series* $\sum x_n$ converges at all, a simple counter-example is a constant non-zero sequence.

The series $\sum x_n$ is convergent if the sequence $(s_n)_n$ of partial sums $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ is convergent. With $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \Vert x_k \Vert$ we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
\sum \Vert x_n \Vert \text{ convergent} & \iff (S_n)_n \text{ convergent} & \implies & (S_n)_n \text{ Cauchy} \\
& & & \Downarrow \\
\sum x_n \text{ convergent} & \iff (s_n)_n \text{ convergent} & \implies & (s_n)_n \text{ Cauchy} \\
\Downarrow \\
\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 0
\end{matrix}
$$

If $X$ is complete then the horizontal implications are equivalences, to that
$$ 
\sum \Vert x_n \Vert \text{ convergent}  \implies \sum  x_n  \text{ convergent} \, .
$$

But again, $(x_n)$ being Cauchy (or convergent) does not imply that $\sum  x_n $ is convergent (conditionally or absolutely).